# linear independence and vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

True or false - be $V$ vector space and $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\in V$ (different from each other).

if the group $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$ have linear independence, so $Sp\{v_{1},v_{2}\}=Sp\{v_{1}+v_{3},v_{2}+v_{3}\}$

Comment: Try the base vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Also don't call it a group.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v_1=\alpha(v_1+v_3)+\beta(v_2+v_3)$; then
$$
(\alpha-1)v_1+\beta v_2+(\alpha+\beta)v_3=0
$$
By linear independence of $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, we get
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha-1=0 \\
\beta=0\\
\alpha+\beta=0
\end{cases}
$$
Can you go on?